# Asymptotes Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In photography, Focal length of a lens, $F$, is linked to the distance from the object ($x$) and the distance to the image ($y$) by the equation:  $$\frac 1F = \frac 1x+\frac 1y$$

See, for example, [Focal Length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focal_length)

Given that $F=65$, Why would it be the case that both horizontal and vertical asymptote would be at $65$?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: This question makes no sense. Where does it come from?

Comment: Did you forget to include (all of the) details about the problem?

Comment: In order for a film camera with a fixed focal length F to focus on an object located a distance x from the lens, the film must be placed a distance y behind the lens. F, y, and x are related as follows:
image
Now suppose a camera has a lens with focal length F = 65.

Comment: I assume that "image" in your last comment was intended to link to a picture of the expression you had in mind?

Comment: Do you mean the usual formula $\frac 1F=\frac 1x+\frac 1y$ or something else?   If that's what you mean, note that, you can't have $x=F$ or $y=F$.  Perhaps that's what you mean by asymptotes?  Though how you thought we could guess all this eludes me.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean.

Comment: Ok.  Then is my explanation sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the basic equation can be rewritten as $$x=\frac {Fy}{y-F}\quad \text {or}\quad y=\frac {Fx}{x-F}$$

Writing it this way makes it clear that letting $x$ or $y$ approach $F$ will cause the other to go to $\pm \infty$, which I believe is what you are asking.